# Deploying React webpage to Github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

So I am trying to deploy a webpage using ReactJS so far the only thing on the page, is a navbar, I thought i was doing everything correctly but when i type in https://myusername.github.io/WulfDevelopments/public/index.html it only displays a blank screen in the inspect im getting a lot of "cant find resources" and 404 errors, it is also targeting my index.js page at line 1, in these errors.

i followed the react github deploy examples, and yet when i try to access the site... nothing..

```js
{
  "name": "personal-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://cnfishead.github.io/WulfDevelopments/public/index.html",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I did run `npm run build` command everything came out fine, i even tried targeting the index.html (as you can see above) and removing public/index.html nothing returns anything useable.

any direction is greatly appreciated

-----Edits -------

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="\public\Favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="src\index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the repo?

Comment: Change `homepage` to `https://cnfishead.github.io/WulfDevelopments`

Comment: @Vishnudev the repo appears to be set to private

Comment: Fix what @Ashraf said and did you run `npm run deploy`?

Comment: I just ran npm run deploy, and it returned an error, failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repo with a configured origin..) however when i ran it earlier i didnt get this. and ill change what ashraf said and let you guys know

Comment: I did change a few things around, and it seems to still be targeting my index.js in the src folder, as if it cannot get access to that file. this may have something to do with it

Ill update my question with the index.html page

Comment: @Vishnudev here is the link to the repo, it shouldnt be set to private, so i dont know know whats up with that 
https://github.com/CNFishead/WulfDevelopments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:-

```
npm i gh-pages
```

In package.json I added

```
 "scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

And Updated

```
"homepage": "http://username.github.io/projectName"
```

Then I did `npm run deploy`

You can check my repositories where I had deployed react apps on GitHub pages. [Working fine for me]
https://github.com/bikkimahato/React-Drag-and-Drop-Chessboard

https://github.com/bikkimahato/react-table-project-redux

Comment: It keeps erroring out, saying "Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin 
remote or must be configured with the "repo" option)."

Comment: @AustinHoward Please check:-

Add the GitHub repository as a "remote" in your local git repository.

`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/projectName.git`

Comment: thanks that allowed me to run the deploy phase.

Comment: Ok, so bit of an update, after playing around for a bit ive finally found out what was causing the problem, i was trying to deploy the code from the main branch, instead of gh-pages branch created from run npm deploy phase. when i changed the directory of the root. it finally works, so if i target the index.html page. it will display content. ableit not what i coded... but content nonetheless i can actually see the code and what it looks like.

so the answer was a hodepodge of stuff, i needed to add the origin, run npm deploy, and other things, i appreciate the help guys!